# ubuntu server 20.04 wifi connection

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet

I have ubuntu server 20.04 installed in a compaq laptop. When wired, it connects to the internet. I have been trying to connect it via wireless without success.I have read a number of articles on using netplan online and tried their instructions without success. the command:
"ip a" produces the following output.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:16:d1:af:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wls1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:2c:63:3f:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e3:f9:bf:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Can somebody please help me to bring up the 'wls1' interface? or is there another issue here?

Thanks.
eoo.

The command 'iwconfig wls1' yielded as follows:

```
wls1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Results of cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml :

```
scr# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp1s0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
            wls1:
                    dhcp4: true
                    optional: true
                    access-points:
                            "A-----66a":
                                    password: "7m-----k8y"
```

@Heynnema
Please find below the current edited *yaml file Ihave according to your suggestion:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd 
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wls1:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "AT-----66a":
           password: "7m------rk8y"
```

The problem remained after applying and rebooting.
Below is the output of the command 'ip a':

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:16:d1:af:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::21f:16ff:fed1:afb7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wls1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:2c:63:3f:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:47:8f:bc:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether 32:06:6d:56:99:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.11.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3006:6dff:fe56:9934/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

@heynnema Please find below the outputs of the commands given:

For 'sudo netplan --debug generate', I had :

```
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.906: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.906: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.906: wls1: adding wifi AP 'ATTc58k66a'
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.906: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: wls1: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: enp1s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: Generating output files..
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: openvswitch: definition enp1s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: NetworkManager: definition enp1s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: Creating wpa_supplicant config
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: wls1: Creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wls1.conf
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: Creating wpa_supplicant unit /run/systemd/system/netplan-wpa-wls1.service
(generate:1099813): GLib-DEBUG: 03:18:36.907: posix_spawn avoided (workdir specified) (fd close requested) 
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.926: Creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.wants/netplan-wpa-wls1.service
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.926: openvswitch: definition wls1 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:1099813): DEBUG: 03:18:36.927: NetworkManager: definition wls1 is not for us (backend 1)
(generate:1099813): GLib-DEBUG: 03:18:36.927: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
(generate:1099813): GLib-DEBUG: 03:18:36.934: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
```

And for the command 'sudo lshw -C network' I had :

```
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1f:16:d1:af:b7
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.124 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0410000-d0410fff memory:d0400000-d040ffff memory:d3700000-d371ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wls1
       version: 01
       serial: 00:24:2c:63:3f:09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=5.4.0-66-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:d2600000-d260ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: flannel.1
       serial: 32:06:6d:56:99:34
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vxlan driverversion=0.1 ip=10.1.11.0 link=yes multicast=yes
```

The command " grep -i wls1 /var/log/syslog*" outputs as follows:

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:26:33 eooubuserver systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant for netplan wls1.
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:26:33 eooubuserver systemd-networkd[857]: wls1: Interface name change detected, wls1 has been renamed to wlan0.
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:26:33 eooubuserver systemd-networkd[857]: wlan0: Interface name change detected, wlan0 has been renamed to wls1.
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:26:33 eooubuserver systemd-networkd[857]: wls1: Link UP
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:26:33 eooubuserver systemd-networkd[857]: wls1: IPv6 successfully enabled
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:26:33 eooubuserver cloud-init[867]: ci-info: |  wls1  | False |                    .                     |       .       |   .    | 00:24:2c:63:3f:09 |
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:26:33 eooubuserver kernel: [   15.765134] ath5k 0000:02:00.0 wls1: renamed from wlan0
```

The command "iwlist wls1 freq" shows as follows:

```
wls1      11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1318551/edit) to include the complete output of `iwconfig wls1`

Comment: @heynnema I have submitted the edit of my question to show the output of the command  "grep -i wls1 /var/log/syslog*

Answer (score 0):

For wireless to work in a server installation, you need to install `wpasupplicant` and `net-tools`.

Using the wired connection...

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install wpasupplicant net-tools`

`reboot`

Your /etc/netplan/*.yaml should look EXACTLY like this:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wls1:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "A-----66a":
          password: "7m-----k8y"
```

Then create `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` with the contents:

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

Then:

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: I did as you suggested without success yet. After editing the /etc/netplan/*yaml file, EXACTLY as suggested, I kept getting the error of indentation at wls1 level . I worked and tried to correct that, then came another error of unknown renderer 'networkd'. I enclosed that in a double quotation mark. With that 'sudo netplan generate' command stopped producing more errors. However. after applying netplan and rebooting. the problem remained. Thank you so much for continuing to assist me in this, I appreciate the time you are giving me in it. What else can I try?

Comment: @eoo Sorry. My error. Try my .yaml file now. Remove the double quotes that you added yourself. Did you already install wpasupplicant? Report back.

Comment: @eoo If you have more problems with the .yaml, edit your question and show me your current .yaml with `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Use copy/paste, then select the pasted text, then click the {} icon to format that text.

Comment: @ heynnema I am still having the probem . I have submitted the file as asked. Thanks.

Comment: @eoo Did you install wpasupplicant? Edit your question and show me the output of `sudo netplan --debug generate` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Also, no space in @heynnema. Thanks!

Comment: @eoo Thanks for the new data. Whenever you add data to your question, or in the comments, be sure to send me a comment that starts with "@heynnema" (no quotes), or I'll miss the updates. You didn't answer my question about wpasupplicant. Also, is the network hidden, or does the password contain any special characters or spaces?

Comment: Yes @heynnema. I did install wpasupplicant

Comment: Yes I did install wpasupplicant and I have edited my question to show the outputs of the commands you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Did you reboot after installing wpasupplicant? You also didn't answer "is the network hidden, or does the password contain any special characters or spaces?"? Edit your question and show me `grep -i wls1 /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @eoo Status please...

Comment: Did you see the output of the command  'lshw -C  network's and the one for  'netplan  - - debug generate ' you asked me to send ?

Comment: that is the status.  I still have the problem - no wireless wifi connection.

Comment: @eoo  You didn't answer my questions in the comment from 2 days ago. Did you reboot? Is the wireless network hidden, or does the password contain any special characters or spaces? Edit your question and show me `iwlist wls1 freq`, and tell me what channel is the wireless network set to in your router?

Comment: I see something like "firmware=N/A" with the output of the command 'lshw......etc' . Can I be having a firmware issue with this wls1 adapter in this laptop,?

Comment: @eoo You **STILL** didn't answer my questions. I don't want to beg you for answers, but if you expect the help, then you'll need to be more responsive, without me having to ask the same questions over and over.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Maybe I misunderstood.   I'm out of state now.  When I get back l will look at it again and get back to you.  Thank you.

Comment: I have submitted the edit of my question to show the output of the command  "grep -i wls1 /var/log/syslog* Also in answer to whether my network is hidden, I don't believe so since my other laptops and desktops discover and connect to the same network. I have a "+" symbol (without the double quotes) in the password of the ssid. Thank you. eoo.

Comment: @eoo Thanks for the updates. You forgot "Edit your question and show me `iwlist wls1 freq`, and tell me what channel is the wireless network set to in your router?".

Comment: Pardom me . An oversite. I have  edited my question accordingly to show the output of "iwlist wls1 freq." Thanks.

Comment: @eoo What about the second part of my question. Please pay attention.

Comment: Please how do I know the channel my wireless network is set to in my router?

Comment: @eoo Log into the router's web admin page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot see the channel setting when I open the page. Please help me  here.

Comment: @eoo Go to the Wireless setup page, or the Advanced Wireless setup page, and you'll find the channel setting there. It'll either be set to AUTO, or channels 1-11.

Comment: Ah, I finally found it. Sorry. The channel is set to Automatic.

Comment: @eoo Then I'm sorry, but I don't know what's wrong with your wireless.